# Using C# to connect to ConnectWise API

Tags: c#, rest, api

I intend to create a program using C# which will update tickets in ConnectWise using, eventually, data from another API.

Thus far I've wanted to test to `GET` some invoices. For this I installed the latest SDK and referenced it in Visual studio (SDK 2017.3).

The documentation claims that this should suffice:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConnectWiseDotNetSDK;
using ConnectWiseDotNetSDK.ConnectWise;
using ConnectWiseDotNetSDK.ConnectWise.Client;
using ConnectWiseDotNetSDK.ConnectWise.Client.System.Api;
using ConnectWiseDotNetSDK.ConnectWise.Client.System.Model;

private static List<Invoice> getInvoices()
{
    var client = getApiClient();
    var invoicesApi = new InvoiceApi(client);
    var response = invoicesApi.GetInvoices();
    var invoices = response.GetResult<List<Invoice>>();
    foreach (var invoice in invoices)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(invoice);
    }
    return invoices;
}
```

(where I have added all the `using ....` rows, the documentation does not clarify which are needed).

This however gives me an error that `getApiClient() does not exist in this context`. I reckon I must create the function, which will provide my authentication etc. Thus I've done:

```
private static getApiClient()
{
    string BaseUri = "https://eu-myconnectwise.net/v4_6_Release/apis/3.0/finance/invoices"
    string ContentType = "application/json";
    string Authstring = "xxxxyyxxxx";
}
```

This does not work. I have no idea how to create the `client` variable in the main program.

Has anyone gotten the SDK to work using C#?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, while the Connectwise documentation is getting better, there's still a whole heap of digging around that you have to do to get the end result you're after.

Here's a short example based on the ZIP file at the bottom of the answer.

```
const string cw_app_id = "<YourAppID>";
const string cw_site = "<YourConnectWiseInstance>";
const string cw_companyname = "<YourConnectWiseCompany>";

const string public_key = "<PublicKey>";
const string private_key = "<PrivateKey>";

private static ApiClient GetApiClient()
{
    return new ApiClient(cw_app_id, cw_site, cw_companyname)
               .SetPublicPrivateKey(public_key, private_key);
}

private static List<Invoice> getInvoices()
{
    var client = getApiClient();
    var invoicesApi = new InvoiceApi(client);
    var response = invoicesApi.GetInvoices();
    var invoices = response.GetResult<List<Invoice>>();
    foreach (var invoice in invoices)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(invoice.invoiceNumber);
    }
    return invoices;
}
```

Assuming you don't already have them or know what each part is:

- Your App ID comes from here: https://developer.connectwise.com/Manage/Cookies
- Your Connectwise Instance is hostname you use to connect
- Your company is the "Company" field on the login screen
- Your public and private keys are generated after creating an API Member (System->Members->API Members) and going to the "API Keys" tab for the new API Member.

On the following page, right hand side, there's a link to download the sample code.

https://developer.connectwise.com/Manage/SDK

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool SoapUI ([enter link description here](https://www.soapui.org/)).
This tool helps you to test all different WEB Interfaces.